# How do I make div background color certain size with contents having position absolute?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a div have a background color with a specific size, but whenever i put position absolute on the content inside of the div it removes the background color.

Heres an image of what i'm trying to do:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
    
    
.background {
  position: relative;
  background: #DFEDFF;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
    
.hero-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
    
.title {
  font-size: 8.4375rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 130px;
  margin: 0;
}
    
.description {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2.75rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
      <div class="hero">
        <div class="hero-text">
          <h1 class="title">Hello,<br>I'm Ian</h1>
          <p class="description">Website coming soon.</p>
        </div>
        <img class="callum" src="images/callum.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Which of the result do you want to achieve. Should your design look like the image or fiddle result??

Comment: @FridayAmeh The image please

Comment: Here's a stab at it--is this helpful? https://jsfiddle.net/3pL5srvq/2/

Answer (score 0):

When you make an element `position:absolute;` it's width/height will no longer influence the width and height of it's parent element. The div's height is defined by its child if there is no set height specified (100% doesn't really work, thats just css magic for you).

If there is no child to give it a height (because it has been discounted because it is now `position:absolute;`) you need to set a specific `px` height for your div eg `height:100px`

Answer (score 0):

I Applied min-height to main_container 410px and then both set absolute ,background div and hero-text
,hero-text setup in center just like you already did and then set left 100px to background so it will start setting up background by leaving 100px space, top:10px ,bottom:10px,right:10px so on....

```css
.main_container{
  min-height:410px;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}

.title {
  font-size: 8.4375rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 130px;
  margin: 0;
}

.description {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2.75rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.background{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  left:100px;
  right:10px;
  content:'';
  display:block;
  background:#DEEDFE;
  z-index:-1;
}

.hero-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container">
<div class="background"></div>
    <div class="hero-text">
      <h1 class="title">Hello,<br>I'm Ian</h1>
      <p class="description">Website coming soon.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/3pL5srvq/1/

the background will auto growth height by hero-text.

`calc(25% - 4rem)` means a position to center and offset-top by padding space(3rem) + balance height up to you, I just set to 1rem

- 25% to center
- -4rem (remove padding-top space(3rem) + balance offset-top(1rem))

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
    
    
.background {
      position: relative;
    background: #DFEDFF;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.hero-text {
    transform: translate(-5% , calc(25% - 4rem));
    padding: 3rem 0;
}

p.description {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
      <div class="hero">
        <div class="hero-text">
          <h1 class="title">Hello,<br>I'm Ian</h1>
          <p class="description">Website coming soon.</p>
        </div>
        <img class="callum" src="images/callum.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
```